# MVC - Controller - Make a Simple Math Calculation - Variable + 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a little problem to make a simple math calculation in the controller.

what I try to do is add +1 to a number of a variable.

Here is an example for you to understand better what I try to do:

```
 var a= formcollection["Id_this"];

 var next = a + 1;
```

**Note:** the value of "`Id_this`" is `"1"`.

The result I need for the variable `next` is `2`

My problem is that the result of the variable `next` is `"12"`.

Comment: Isn't the value `"1"` instead of `1`? What is the error message when you replace `var next` with `int next`? What result do you get now?

Comment: @HansKesting: I fixed that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` is a `string`. Adding a number to a string results in the number being converted to a string and being concatenated.

To make it work, you first need to convert `a` to a number:

```
var next = Convert.ToInt32(a) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason is you are doing string concatenation. Try this safe approach:

```
int number;
int next = 0;

if(Int32.TryParse(formcollection["Id_this"], out number))
{
   next = number + 1;
}
else
{
   //formcollection["Id_this"] is not a number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this :

```
var next = int.Parse(a) + 1;
```

Comment: `Int32.Parse()`, `Int32.TryParse()` or `Convert.ToInt32()`